# html css link into another link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Here is my problem : 
I've try to add a "link" into another one. Explanation :
I have an image, which is inside a link, so when I click anywhere on this image I'm redirected to the page I want. What I'm trying to do is, to add a small "edit icon" at the top right corner of this image, so I can edit its properties on another page dedicated to this.

The fact is that I want to have this "edit icon" as a link, when I click on it I want to be redirected on another page, not the page which is the url of the main image container link...

so the code looks like this :

```
<a href...>
    <span ... with style : size and background image so it looks like a clickable picture...>

        <a href...>
            <span... the second span with another background (edit icon), FLOAT RIGHT (to get it in the corner of the container span) and small sized...>
            </span>
        </a>

    </span>

</a>
```

If I do things this way, the second block (edit icon) appears OUT OF the container...
and if I change my order. It sometimes appears but it's not clickable. What am i doing wrong? is it impossible to make links into links? or is it a special way to do that?

Comment: You'd rather use `div` instead of `span` ?

Comment: if i do, the "contained" link is clickable, but the "container" link, (all around the 2nd one) is no more clickable... :(

Comment: Well, nested `a` element isn't that good anyway. You should consider having two splitted `a` and position the "edit" one on the "image" one (position, z-index, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't place a link into an other one. You should place the links each after like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="show" href="link1.html"><div></div></a>
    <a id="edit" href="edit.html"><div></div></a>
</div>
```

Here is an example for you :
http://jsfiddle.net/gXV73/1/

Comment: well, this is not wht i'm tryin to do... the fact is that i want to have my 2nd link OVER the first one... (so the "big image" contains the smaller one somewhere on it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different images, one for the edit icon and one will be your main big image.

Put both the images in two different divs, and use  `position:absolute;`  and  `z-index:100; left:/*something*/; right:/*something*/` for the small edit image div.

or show me the code so that i can help better.

Comment: absolute positionning doesnt solve my problem... as i said above, i'm tryin to have my 2nd pic over the first one... if i use a responsive page the absolute positionning isnt good... the position of the 2nd element should be relative to the first one... but can't do it properly... my 2nd picture is ALWAYS under the 1st one... even if i put the 1st image as "background-img" of the div, and put my 2nd picture as a simple <img> into that div... if i do that, the img is link clickable, but the container div is no more clickable... (soo hard to explain for me^^ sorry for my "bad" english guys...)